# Servlet not found once hosted on a web server

Tags: gwt

The main problem is that the servlet is basically not found on the web server once I upload it to some webhosting server I got, while it finds it all fine and dandy in hosted mode with the embedded jetty

I can't really check the full tomcat setup on the host, but it's actually there as some .jsp test files run fine there, unless there's something missing that I'm not sure of

When going directly to the path of the servlet, when in hosted mode it does the
HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL,
while just 404 on the webserver

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

<!-- Servlets -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>retailQuery</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.retail.report.server.DBConnectionServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>retailQuery</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/retailreport/retailQuery</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>RetailReport.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

RetailReport.gwt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='retailreport'>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>

<!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
<entry-point class='com.retail.report.client.RetailReport'/> 

<servlet class="com.retail.report.server.DBConnectionServiceImpl"
    path="/retailQuery" />
```

DBConnectionServiceImpl:

package com.retail.report.client;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("retailQuery")
public interface DBConnectionService extends RemoteService {

    public ArrayList<SalesEntry> dayOfWeekQuery(String hier);

    public ArrayList<SalesEntry> weekQuery(String hier);
}
```

As far as I can see, everything seems to be normal when looking at similar problems with servlets not being found, the only thing I cant check 100% for sure is any tomcat settings that I don't know about that need to be set, since it's some shared tomcat server on the webhost that I cant change anything with myself (although can probably ask the hosting if there's actually something that needs to change)

Answer (score 1):

What is inside your *tomcat/lib* folder on the host? It is possible that GWT assumes some libraries are available on the hosted mode, but they are missing from your deployed version's host libraries. Just make sure all needed .jar files are in the war file in *classes* or *lib*.

Comment: The some sort of a lib missing would make sense, although I am not entirely sure which one it would be, as gwt-servlet.jar is there which would be the main one.
Should I straight up try copying every library I have in the classpath into the web-inf/lib folder?

catalina-cluster.jar
commons-modeler-2.0.1.jar
servlets-ssi.renametojar
tomcat-coyote.jar
catalina-optional.jar
servlets-cgi.renametojar
servlets-webdav.jar
tomcat-http.jar
catalina-ant-jmx.jar
catalina-storeconfig.jar
servlets-default.jar
tomcat-ajp.jar
tomcat-util.jar
catalina-ant.jar
catalina.jar
servlets-invoker.jar
tomcat-apr.jar

Comment: @Alex No need to copy them all, just make sure you can find all of them in .war and they should end up on the Tomcat classpath.

Comment: With all of the libraries in the .war it still cannot find the servlets

Comment: @Alex Hmm, perhaps your compiled classes are not all getting placed into the .war? What is the stack trace you get?

Comment: All of the compiled classes are in there in WEB-INF/classes
There isn't really any errors for a stack trace, it just tries to do the post

POST http://HOSTNAME/retailreport/retailQuery 404 Not Found 112ms
the post itself is something like
7|0|4|http://HOSTNAME/retailreport/|2DE442498527422A67A79370E8958C92|com.retail.report.client.DBConnectionService|weekQuery|1|2|3|4|0|

Comment: Well narrowed it down to a compilation issue or a server issue, since the starter project (greet service) has the same problem with not being able to find the servlet